# Microsoft WCF LOB Adapter SDK is installed, but component is required

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I tried to install BizTalk 2013 R2 LOB Adapter SDK but it returned the below error

> Microsoft WCF LOB Adapter SDK is installed but the following components are not installed
>   - Tools component is required to develop applications using Visual Studio

[image: BizTalk 2013 R2 installation screen]
I installed BizTalk 2013 R2, SQL server 2014 and visual studio 2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BizTalk Server 2013 R2 requires **Visual Studio 2013** to develop applications.

Visual Studio 2017 is not supported.

[Hardware and Software Requirements for BizTalk Server 2013 and 2013 R2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/install-and-config-guides/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-biztalk-server-2013-and-2013-r2)